# Real Closed Field, Degree of Monic/Irreducible

Tags: field-theory

In a real closed field, $R$, why do all monic irreducible polynomials $f(x) \in R[x]$ have at most degree 1 or 2?

Answer (score 0):

I'll take as the definition of "real closed field" that $R(\sqrt{-1})$ is algebraically closed but $R$ is not. Then any number $a+b\sqrt{-1}$ has minimal polynomial of degree at most $2$ over $R$, since it is a root of $$t^2 - 2a \cdot t + (a^2+b^2).$$